# Need to build javascript app using build.yaml in Azuredevops

Tags: javascript, build, azure-devops, yaml

I have to build javascript app through build.yaml using Azuredevops and as per microsoft documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-azure-devops I'm unable to run it as I'm struck with 
"An error occurred while loading the YAML build pipeline. wrong number of segments" exception

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

trigger:
  batch: false
  branches:
    include:
    - '*'
  paths:
    exclude:
    - 'Currency/*'
steps:
- bash: |
    if [ -f Convertor.csproj ]
    then
        dotnet build Convertor.csproj --output ./bin
    fi
    npm install 
    npm run build --if-present
    npm prune --production
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: "Archive files"
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip"
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    artifactName: 'drop'
```

This is my build.yaml

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the error? with the yaml file.

Comment: should `name: 'drop'` be `artifactName: 'drop'` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops

Comment: @JaromandaX so I have chamnged the name to artifactName but it didn't  helped

Comment: My build.yaml is added in the description and error which I'm getting is "An error occurred while loading the YAML build pipeline. wrong number of segment"

Comment: have you checked that `inputs` in  `task: ArchiveFiles@2` are also correct

Comment: yes,but not sure what is the issue as it doesn't describe much other than throwing one line of error,do you have example where you have deployed js app using pipeline

Comment: I tried your yaml and is work fine, please attach a screenshot from the yaml editor.

Answer (score 0):

The build.yaml of yours worked fine on my AzureDevops. You can try creating a new pipeline using the wizard in azure devops. And copy your build.yaml to the YAML editor, and check if the editor underlines something.

You can find an example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/javascript?view=azure-devops) about building/testing/deploying JavaScript apps given by Microsoft.